# is there a "when" in programming as oppose to if/else if etc?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

what i mean is, is there a way in AS3, or in programming in general(php, js etc) to make an event fire/activate "WHEN" something does something, as oppose to an if/else if / else statements ?

for example, say i want to make an event fire /activate ONLY when a frame label is hit, and thereafter , do something else etc, essentially making it do things one by one down the line according to WHEN certain objectives are met. is there a "when" type of statement etc that will do this as oppose to if/else if etc???

for example, using the above example, instead of me doing something like this:

```
Code:
xyz.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME / or INIT , btn);

function btn(e:Event):void{
    if ( externalSwf.currentFrameLabel == " label here "){
          do something code here.
    }

}
```

is there a way to do it like this:

```
Code:
xyz.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME / or INIT , btn);

function btn(e:Event):void{
    when ( externalSwf.currentFrameLabel == " label here "){
          do this.


          when (this happens){ 
        do this next
}
    }

}
```

etc...

how can one accomplish that?

reason i ask is because i have a little project im working on (smooth transitions of external swfs code) that is partly working but i cant for the life of me, figure out how to implement a structure like what i have directly above.

essentially what im saying is ,i dont need conditionals i need.. certainty...if that makes sense lol.

hope its not confusing.

any tips ideas etc i gladly appreciate.

thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you need to save some sort of state as to how far along the progression of events has gone. (And state transitions will be triggered by eventhandlers).

Comment: I don't see the difference between the normal `if` and your `when` keyword. Can you add an example of how it behaves different?

Comment: I think he wants `when` to behave like: "return control flow, but come back here as soon as this new condition is met".

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is already done by events. For example, an event fires *when* a new frame is about to be rendered. Then you can check *if* that frame has a specific label.

For the frame label example, you could create a custom listener which fires only on frames you want. In that case your `when` block would be a callback function.

```
frameLabelEventDispatcher.addEventListener("label here", whenLabel);

function whenLabel() { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when value some property (e.g. `prop`) of some object (e.g. of type `Example` extending `EventDispatcher`), you should throw an event in seter of `prop`. So, I suggest something like the following

```
class Example1 extends Example {
    public static var eventName = "event_name";
    //var prop is declared in Example class
    public function setProp(val: string) {
        prop = val;
        if (prop == "some_value") {
            dispatchEvent(new flah.events.Event(eventName));
        }
    }

    public function init() {
        addEventListener(eventName, handler);
    }

    private function handler(e: Event) {
        //do whatever you like here
    }
}
```

Well, I guess you cought my idea. Hope that will help you!